# Magento1.9 : How to remove cart tabs from customer view tab in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I want to remove `Carts` tab coming in `Customer View` tab in magento admin panel for Manage Customer with a custom condition. As shown in below figure :

[image]

Which block or template file should I override for this?

**EDIT** - I want to remove this when a certain condition match, I have created a module for User role if the condition meet only then want to remove these tabs.

Comment: You mean Shopping cart tabs just below recent orders?

Comment: Please check my updated question.

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: @SukumarGorai Overrides should always be the last option. Better use observers and layout updates when possible.

Comment: @sv3n Yes I know. But if you see the question he wants to override the file. Thats why I have just guide him which class he needs to override. How do you put a condition in your layout updates?

Comment: @SukumarGorai it depends on your needs ... you can use `controller_action_layout_load_before` event and `addHandle()` for own layout handles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to the following class:

> Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion

You will find the whole code here. Override this Block class and put the conditions accordingly

Answer (score 0):

you need to edit `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout\customer.xml`.

find `<block type="adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_view_accordion" name="accordion" />` and comment it.

May be it will work for you

Comment: I have updated my question, Please check.

Comment: @tecjam give proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to all other answers, if you remove the entire accordion block, you will also remove the recent orders and wishlist accordion items, not just the cart ones.

You should overwrite the `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Edit_Tab_View_Accordion` and comment out or remove the following code:

```
    // add shopping cart block of each website
    foreach (Mage::registry('current_customer')->getSharedWebsiteIds() as $websiteId) {
        $website = Mage::app()->getWebsite($websiteId);

        // count cart items
        $cartItemsCount = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
            ->setWebsite($website)->loadByCustomer($customer)
            ->getItemsCollection(false)
            ->addFieldToFilter('parent_item_id', array('null' => true))
            ->getSize();
        // prepare title for cart
        $title = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart - %d item(s)', $cartItemsCount);
        if (count($customer->getSharedWebsiteIds()) > 1) {
            $title = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Shopping Cart of %1$s - %2$d item(s)', $website->getName(), $cartItemsCount);
        }

        // add cart ajax accordion
        $this->addItem('shopingCart' . $websiteId, array(
            'title'   => $title,
            'ajax'    => true,
            'content_url' => $this->getUrl('*/*/viewCart', array('_current' => true, 'website_id' => $websiteId)),
        ));
    }
```

Copy `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/Accordion.php` and do your edits.